# Lambda function works, but fails when invoked through the API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that puts items in a dynamodb table. It works perfectly fine with test events.

```
import boto3

class DBupload:

def __init__(self):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    self.table=client.Table('labels')
    
def Create_data(self,event):
    response=self.table.put_item(
        Item={
            'instanceID' : event['id'],
            'imageID' : event['imageid'],
            'labels' : event['labels']
        }
    )
    return{
        'statusCode' : response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'],
        'body' : 'Record ' + event['id'] + ' added'
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
if event:
    instance =  DBupload()
    if event['tasktype']  == "create":
        create_result =  instance.Create_data(event['data'])
        return create_result
    else :
        return {
            'statusCode': '404',
            'body': 'Not found'
        }
```

I make a REST API gateway, create a resource, and a POST method, with proxy, and I enable IAM and API key, before deploying it. I then go to usage plans, and add the stage to the usage plan, then deploy once more for good measure.

When I send the exact same request now, through Postman, it throws an Internal Server Error. I can send it through the API Gateway testing function which bypasses auth, and it gives me the following error log

[image]

**Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'tasktype'.
Method completed with status: 502**

So it looks like it is NOT an API error because the error log references the customer function in lambda. But the Lambda function works perfectly fine when I send my item in as a test-event through lambda. What gives?

Here is the test event btw

```
{
"tasktype":"create",
"data":{
   "id":"testinsanceid",
   "imageid":"testimageid",
   "labels":{
      "labeltype1":"labelname1",
      "labeltype2":"labelname2"
   }
}
```

}

Comment: At the start of the `lambda_handler()` function, add `print(event)` to see what the event _actually_ contains. It probably isn't what you expect. You can view the output in CloudWatch Logs (via the function's Monitor tab).

Comment: The event through the API gateway is much bigger and has a lot more attributes, but the "body" of that event is the exact same as the test event that I tested on Lambda. It still says that 'tasktype' has a "keyError". Should I be saying event['body/tasktype'] or something to get it to look for 'tasktype' inside the body, instead of just event['tasktype']?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if 'tasktype' in event and event['tasktype']  == "create":
```

This will ensure you're not taking a dependency on something that doesn't exist.

Also `print(event)` will allow you to ensure the event object is what you expect.

Comment: This stops the error from occuring, but just skips over it and goes to the 404. So it is just not even able to read that the event has a tasktype. Is it because tasktype is inside the body inside the event? Should I be doing event['body.tasktype'] or  event.body[tasktype] or something like that?

Comment: Its actually more likely that `event` is a string since you have not parsed it. Please print the value of `event` like I mentioned and also `print(type(event))`